# How to get crash/hangs reports for applications, daemons and OSX programatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, security

I know there is a way to get crashes and hangs for all applications. These files are placed in "/Users/user/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports". So I could get version, time and name of the app.

But how to get daemon/process crashes and hangs? I need to know which exactly daemon was crashed/hanged and time when it happened.

Also is there is a way to get some system(OSX) crash with the same info?

Also would be great to get some resource failures/warnings: out of memory or out of disk space.

I need to get it programatically.

On Windows we can do this using NotifyChangeEventLog () API. All these info we can gather using such method. Also it notifies if something happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the daemons crash/hang report see the "/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports" directory. According to [this document](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts3742) you can also find there kernel panic reports (i.e. system crash).
Don't know about NotifyChangeEventLog-like API, but in situations like "out of memory" there will be an exception, so you just need to catch it. See [Error Handling Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html) for details. Also take a look at [Exception Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html)

**Edit**: for the information about Crash Reporter take a look at Chapter 5 of Levin's book "Mac OS X and iOS Internals: To the Apple's Core"

Comment: I made OSX crash by command "sudo kill 1" but after system reboot didn't find any crash report in "/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports" directory.

Comment: @Sergio, you didn't make OSX crash, you've just terminated lauchd process by sending it SIGTERM. It is just shutdown.

Comment: Even it wasn't OSX crash, OS should generate crash report as well. Because it's a process. Also tried to kill other daemons/processes but no reports generated. Could you please provide some example how to receive process to kill to receive report.

Comment: It shouldn't generate crash report because there is no crash. If you want a crash add some bad code to your application, compile it and run. Something like division by zero or dereferencing of null pointer.

Comment: @Sergio. All this info you can get just by parsing the report name. It  has special format <process_name>_<date>-<time>_<host_name>.<event>. Simple regexp will do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

in 10.9 the activity monitor offers you two tools when you have a hang but no crash hence no crash report:

spindump - memory dump like crash report and
sys digs which produces a bundle of files